# fabric does not work with my python/django code

Tags: python, django, fabric

Here is my content of fabfile.py

```
from fabric.api import run, local, abort, env, put, task
from fabric.contrib.files import exists
from fabric.context_managers import cd, lcd, settings, hide
from fabric.operations import require


PROD_SERVER='user@user.webfactional.com'

# Host and login username:
def prod():
    env.hosts=[PROD_SERVER]
    env.remote_app_dir='~/webapps/django/myapp/'
    env.remote_apache_dir='~/webapps/django/apache2/'

def commit():
    message=raw_input("Enter a git commit message: ")
    local("git add -A && git commit -m '%s'" %message)
    local("git push webfactioncarmarket")
    print "changes pushed to remote repository...."


def test():
    local("python2.7 manage.py test")

def install_dependencies():
    with cd(env.remote_app_dir):
        run("pip2.7 install -r requirements.txt")

def testing_fabric():
    prod()
    print env.hosts
    print env.remote_app_dir
    print env.remote_apache_dir

def collectstatic():
    prod()
    print env.hosts
    require('hosts',provided_by=[prod])
    run ("cd $(remote_app_dir);python2.7 manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

Running :

```
fab testing_fabric #works fine
['user@user.webfactional.com']
~/webapps/django/myapp/
~/webapps/django/myapp/

Done.
```

Running:

```
fab collectstatic
['user@user.webfactional.com']
No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:
```

why do I get this prompt: `No hosts found`. I print `env.hosts` and it prints the host?
how do I fix this?

EDIT: I tried the chaining:
I get this error:

```
run: cd $(remote_app_dir);python2.7 manage.py collectstatic --noinput
out: /bin/bash: remote_app_dir: command not found
```

why can I not pass the value of remote_app_dir does not get passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

- Set env.hosts at the module level, so it gets set when the fabfile is imported
- Chain modules to set the env variable.

In your case, the second one can be accomplished by removing the line `prod()` from `collectstatic` and instead invoking fabric like this:

`fab prod collecstatic`

This sort of decoupling can be immensely powerful. See here: http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/execution.html#globally-via-env

To run from a specific directory, try using `with cd`:

```
def collectstatic():
    with cd(env.remote_app_dir):
        run("python2.7 manage.py collectstatic --noinput")
```

See here: https://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/core/context_managers.html

Comment: Thanks: I tried chaining modules. I get another error which I pasted above in the EDIT. can you help out?

Comment: Edited to answer second question.

Answer (score 2):

I write answer, becaue I don't have enough points to make a comment:

> run ("cd $(remote_app_dir);python2.7 manage.py collectstatic --noinput

You should not use `remote_app_dir` variable (wrapping in it `$()` ) as you would do using bash/shell. First of all, this variable is not available in shell.

`env.remote_app_dir='~/webapps/django/myapp/'`

cause that python object `env` gets new attribute `remote_app_dir`

please change your code and use your variable in pythonic way:

> run ("cd %spython2.7 manage.py collectstatic --noinput" % env.remote_app_dir)

Comment: I moved the variables to module level. still I get same error

Comment: `env` object is not any magical thing which passes variables from python to shell. It is simple AttributeDict (https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/state.py#L305), which should be used to keep some important variables inside fabfile.

If you want to set shell variable, you could do that by `run("export remote_app_dir='~/webapps/django/myapp/'")`

Comment: In this link http://www.morethanseven.net/2009/07/27/fabric-django-git-apache-mod-wsgi-virtualenv-and-p/, I see cd $(path) being used. thats why I used similar call